# How to publish and register an extra Service Provider in Laravel Package

Tags: laravel, service-provider, package-development

I would like to publish an extra service provider into `App/Providers/` and then register it. The problem is I'm supposed to register it in `register()` function while I should publish it in `boot()` function. How should I accomplish that?

Here is what I'm going to and how publish it:

```
public function boot()
{
    if ($this->app->runningInConsole())
    {
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__ . '/Console/stubs/SomeServiceProvider.stub' => 
            app_path('Providers/SomeServiceProvider.php'),
        ], 'wire-provider');
    }
}
```

Here is how I would presumably register it if was published properly:

```
public function register()
{

    $this->app->register(App\Providers\SomeServiceProvider::class);
}
```

I would like to point this out, this service provider is not the main service provider for the package, and it's not in the project by default, it should be published first.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot do that. But anyway, I would highly discourage from registering application code in a vendor package. Official packages like Laravel Telescope don't do this either. Partially, because one can change the application namespace from `App\` to something else, breaking the whole package.

Comment: If you checked Nova it also publishes NovaServiceProvider, but it also registers it somehow. I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I mean, you can check if the file exists before registering it...

Comment: Hmm, yeah that makes sense